QRegExp with AND operator
Let's try again...
I need to write a QRegExp expression for my program which contains multiple keywords which I get from a QDialog to then filter a QTableView with a QSortFilterProxyModel.
I have:
characteristics = self.dialog.returnvalues()
search = '|'.join(characteristics)
self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(search))

which works fine, but I need to write a search with the AND operator, not OR.
Someone linked me to this when I tried asking this question previously, but like I said there, I'm still learning Python and PyQt and I don't know how to convert what I learned into my program. I tried to do this:
newchar = []
for ch in characteristics:
    newchar.append('(?=.*' + ch + ')')
search = '^' + ''.join(newchar) + '.$'

but as I call the function my view turns blank. Can you tell me what to do? Let me say it better, can you write down what should I do, without any link? Last time someone just converted my question as a duplicate and linked me to the post I mentioned; though I appreciate the help, I'm just not good enough to go on on my own, thanks for the consideration.

Which function? Which view?

@MichaelButscher the function I call to filter my QTableView.

.$ should be .*$.

Without the *, it only matches a value that's exactly 1 character long.

And unless setFilterRegExp() requires the regexp to match the entire string, you don't need ^ or .*$ at all. See this answer for the simplest case.

So try just search = ''.join(newchar)

@Barmar still doesn't work, sadly. Maybe I'm approaching this incorrectly? I have to filter a list of strings in the chosen column with a series of characteristics, like 'Action, Adventure,  Comedy, Dramatic' (this is just a possible string, some of them have more characteristics, other even less), but whatever I try using as a QRegExp it just empties the view.

If you create a regexp like (?=.*Adventure)(?=.*Comedy) by hand, does it work?

Consider switching to QRegularExpression, which is more compliant than QRegExp.

@Barmar I tried it like this: self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp('(?=.*Adventure)(?=.*Comedy)')), but once again it just blanked the table

@FabioCricelli I already gave you the code in your previous question, which I will repeat here: QRegExp(''.join(f'(?=.*{QRegExp.escape(c)})' for c in char_list)). This works perfectly fine for me. By default, it will do a case-sensitive search for text that contains all of the substrings in any order. If it doesn't work for you, you must be making some other mistake which is not shown in your question. Thus, you will need to provide a proper [mre] if you want further help.

@musicamante Thanks for the tip, I'll try switching (read experimenting and hoping for luck) to QRegularExpression

@ekhumoro sorry about it, but whatever the reason, your reply wasn't marked and my question wouldn't open whatever I did, so I just saw your reply; anyway, I tried pasting what you wrote, and it didn't work. About my code, the function is exactly as you see it in my question: I get a list of characteristics from my dialog (i.e. ['Action', 'Dramatic'], I set the column for the filtering, and then I set the QRegExp; if I just insert one value, everything's fine, otherwise the filtering doesn't work. What else should I provide? The rest of the code has no problem, just this function has

@FabioCricelli It does work - I know, because I tested it. I cannot debug code I cannot see. Verbal descriptions are no use. Please provide an proper [mre] as requested. (Long experience tells me that if you make the effort to create a simplified test case, you'll probably find the problem yourself anyway).

@ekhumoro Just in case it's needed, I follower what another site said about creating the filtering with self.proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel(), self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model), self.tableView.setModel(self.proxy). I have other functions in my code which use the filtering and they work perfectly, but they have only one parameter for the QRegExp.

@FabioCricelli If it still doesn't work, you have to provide a proper and comprehensive MRE. Note that this does not mean that you need to post your full code, but a code properly tailored for the question, that allows us to reproduce the problem while including only what's relevant to it ("minimal"). We should have a code that won't have more than 150-200 lines and that we can easily copy, paste and run without any substantial edits. Creating such an example isn't immediate, but it's also a fundamental step in debugging and problem solving. Without it, we cannot help you in any way.

@ekhumoro I'm the biggest idiot in the whole world, or I suck at coding, or both! How in the world the program could find anything at all, if I set the entire column as void? The same model is used for two different tables, so I set it to show different things according to the view, and of course my genius self forgot about it! Sorry for the wining, your solution works amazingly, thanks a lot

@FabioCricelli No problem. We all make mistakes like this. Sometimes it just takes a little extra time to see the obvious...
